# Linear Algebra: Finding Basis for Column Space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In class I was taught that you can find a basis for the column space of a matrix A by reducing it to row reduced form. Then you can use the column vectors that correspond to the leading 1’s of the rows. I understand how these vectors are linearly independent and that dimension of these vectors is equal to that of the row space, but how can I prove that they span exactly the column space?

Comment: The key is that the other columns are all linear combinations of this linearly-independent set.

Answer (score 1):

Show that each elimination step (Subtracting a multiple of a row from another row to create the zeroes under the pivots) is invertible and preserves the column space: each new column is a lin. comb. of old column and we can go back too.

Comment: Err... elementary row operations preserve the _row_ space. They change the column space, although they do preserve dependencies among the columns.